# Swift : Difference between sources and resources folders in playground file? why sources folder has swift logo?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

What is the difference between Sources and Resources folders in swift playground file? Why Sources folder has swift logo on it? what all we can put in each folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sources is for supporting Swift source code that you want to be available to the playground.  Resources is for resource files like images, plists, etc.

Comment: In terms of access they are both the same right? It's just a convenience. Right?